# how to delete storage account Container (blob) using AzureRM cmdlet and i have power shell version is 5.1

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-5.0

I tried to delete storage account using the below command:

```
Remove-AzureRmStorageContainer -StorageAccount $stg -ContainerName "002fc90e-dc20-40f5-bf2f-b4998c4d6a77g" -force -verbose
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
Remove-AzureRmStorageContainer : The term '**Remove-AzureRmStorageContainer' is not recognized** as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureRmStorageContainer -StorageAccount $stg -ContainerName "0 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-AzureRmStorageContainer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `Enable-AzureRmAlias` cmdlet before you run the `Remove-AzureRmStorageContainer` if you have [upgraded to new Azure Powershell Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.1.0#upgrade-to-az). This cmdlet enables a compatibility mode through aliases, to allow you to use existing scripts with minimal modification while working towards a full migration to Az. See [Migrate existing scripts to Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.1.0#migrate-existing-scripts-to-az) for more details.